# How to click on element through "data-ng-click" attribute using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How can I send a click to the following elements using Selenium?

Note: They are placed at the same page and both of them have the same class "btn btn-primary"

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ctrl.findInstrumentsBySearch(ctrl.filterInstrument);" data-ng-disabled="ctrl.disableButtonSearchInstrument();">
    <span class="fa fa-search"></span> Pesquisar
</button>
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ctrl.downloadLimitInstrumentCsv(ctrl.filterInstrument,{ filename: &quot;export.csv&quot; });">
    <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span> Exportar
</button>
```

When I try to use the following I receive the error "IndexError: list index out of range":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(("https://line.bvmfnet.com.br/#/limits/1"))
python_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @data-ng-click='ctrl.findInstrumentsBySearch(ctrl.filterInstrument)']")[0]
python_button.click()
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-primary").click()
browser.find_element_by_class_name('data-ng-click').click()
and some other variations...

Comment: Are they in any kind of iframes or not?

Comment: Try css selector .btn.btn-primary .

Comment: Add your current code attempts to your question along with the results. Have you verified that your locators are uniquely identifying the element you want? My guess is that your locators are locating more than one element and the first one (that it's clicking) is not the one you intended to click and so appears to be doing nothing, at least not what you intended.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the error that i'm receiving and also what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the elements with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- **Pesquisar**:

  - Using `css_selector`:

    ```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='findInstrumentsBySearch'][data-ng-disabled*='disableButtonSearchInstrument']").click()
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and contains(@data-ng-click, 'findInstrumentsBySearch')][contains(., 'Pesquisar')]").click()
    ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- **Exportar**:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='downloadLimitInstrumentCsv']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and contains(@data-ng-click, 'downloadLimitInstrumentCsv')][contains(., 'Exportar')]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```